# OS X: What software for cutting videos?

Tags: video

On Windows, I've used [Solveig Multimedia Video Splitter](https://www.solveigmm.com/en/products/video-splitter/) and it will cut the video on exactly the time range listed (example: `00:11:34.004` to `00:34:45.005`)

I've tried a freeware app [LosslessCut](https://electronjs.org/apps/losslesscut) (which uses FFmpeg) and it only trims cuts on the B-frames I think.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to only trim videos, I would recommend checking out ffmpeg. It's easy to use from the mac terminal and is able to trim videos with -ss and -t. For downloads and documentation visit:

[ffmpeg.org](https://ffmpeg.org/)

Answer (score 0):

[image]If you want something free and pretty easy which has visual display as well: [Blender](https://www.blender.org/)

There are loads of tutorials on Youtube how to use this program for various reasons.

It's main usage is 3D Modelling and Rendering, but it also has a very good video editing section, which uses `ffmpeg` for export compression.

It handles both B-frames, frames and ss:mm:hh.